# Cronjob not running, attempting to echo string into file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

My /etc/crontab looks like this:

```
* * * * * echo"Another 5 Minutes! " >> /tmp/5-minutes.txt
```

I figured this would append "Another 5 Minutes! " to /tmp/5-minutes.txt every minute. When I perform a 'less' command on the file, the changes are not there.

EDIT: If it helps, I have one other job in the crontab file, perhaps it's effecting the other job.

```
0 * * * * finger >> /tmp/hourly-finger.txt
* * * * * echo "Another 5 Minutes! " >> /tmp/5-minute.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Because I'm editing the /etc/crontab directly I needed to specify a user for the crontab to run as. In my case I ran it as root so...

```
* * * * * root echo "Another 5 Minutes! : >> /tmp/5-minutes.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a space after `echo`

```
echo "Another 5 Minutes! "
```